# SQL LEFT JOIN using WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have like this tables:

`categorizables`

[image]

Also I have tables `products` and `categories` which doesn't have any foregin keys.

I tried create like this query to count products on each category:

```
SELECT category_id, COUNT(categorizable_id), categories.title 
FROM categorizables 
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = category_id
GROUP BY category_id
```

It works but when I tried add `WHERE` condition then doesn't work:

```
SELECT category_id, COUNT(categorizable_id), categories.title 
FROM categorizables 
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = category_id
WHERE categorizables.categorizable_type = "App\Models\Product"
GROUP BY category_id
```

How I can add `WHERE` condition correctly?

Comment: I am just lost.  You have a table `categorizable` that has both an `id` and a `categorizable_id`.  What kind of naming convention is that?  Is there a `product_id` anywhere?  How are the tables connected?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thats a morph relation.... it uses _type for the model and _id for the id

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Alias all your tables, fully qualify your select list and fully specify your group by (and turn your MySQL ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode on)

Comment: Can you add the code of your select statement?

Comment: This kind of naming convention from Laravel Framework `morphMany` table structure :) @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use apostrophes instead of quotes and escape the backslashes:

```
SELECT category_id, COUNT(categorizable_id), categories.title 
FROM categorizables 
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = category_id
WHERE categorizables.categorizable_type = 'App\\Models\\Product'
GROUP BY category_id
```